# "missing ) after argument list"

Tags: java, javascript, google-docs

Can you please help me with the following code? I'm getting the error "missing ) after argument list".

```
if(warning_count) {
MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@yourdomain.com<script cf-hash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */!function(){try{var t="currentScript"in document?document.currentScript:function(){for(var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute("cf-hash"))return t[e]}();if(t&&t.previousSibling){var e,r,n,i,c=t.previousSibling,a=c.getAttribute("data-cfemail");if(a){for(e="",r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16),n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)i=parseInt(a.substr(n,2),16)^r,e+=String.fromCharCode(i);e=document.createTextNode(e),c.parentNode.replaceChild(e,c)}}}catch(u){}}();/* ]]> */</script>,anotheremail@anotherdomain.com<script cf-hash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */!function(){try{var t="currentScript"in document?document.currentScript:function(){for(var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute("cf-hash"))return t[e]}();if(t&&t.previousSibling){var e,r,n,i,c=t.previousSibling,a=c.getAttribute("data-cfemail");if(a){for(e="",r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16),n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)i=parseInt(a.substr(n,2),16)^r,e+=String.fromCharCode(i);e=document.createTextNode(e),c.parentNode.replaceChild(e,c)}}}catch(u){}}();/* ]]> */</script>",
     "Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
}
```

Comment: You have quotes in your `String`. You need to  escape them. Or better yet, read this from a file.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That seems to me like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @DavidWallace it's a dup.

Comment: I was just looking for a little bit of help being a person who never written a code. I vae removed the quotes from the line with "mail" but still the error appears

Comment: When Boris told you to escape the quotes, he meant precede each one with a backslash.